# Terminals opening in root directory rather than $HOME

Tags: linux, fedora, users, home

I recently moved my home directory to a different disk and now have it mounted on `/home` - which seems to have worked.

However one puzzling thing is any terminal emulator I open (regardless of program, alacritty, rxvt, xterm etc) defaults to opening the `/` directory rather than my home directory `/home/daniel`

I'm not sure what to do to resolve it, I could set `--working-directory` but that seems like a band-aid as my terminals always opened in $HOME before I did the move...

```
/|▶ echo $HOME
/home/daniel
/|▶ finger daniel
Login: daniel               Name: Daniel
Directory: /home/daniel         Shell: /bin/zsh
On since Sun Sep 13 12:49 (BST) on :0 from :0 (messages off)
/|▶ whoami
daniel
/|▶ cd ~
~|▶ 
~|▶ sudo mount | grep home
/dev/sda3 on /home type ext4 (rw,relatime,seclabel)
/|▶ getent passwd $USER
daniel:x:1000:1000:Daniel:/home/daniel:/bin/zsh
/|▶ ls -lZ $HOME
total 68
drwxr-xr-x.  2 daniel daniel unconfined_u:object_r:unlabeled_t:s0  4096 May 25 18:59 Desktop
drwxr-xr-x.  2 daniel daniel unconfined_u:object_r:unlabeled_t:s0  4096 Aug  5 20:36 Documents
drwxr-xr-x.  2 daniel daniel unconfined_u:object_r:unlabeled_t:s0  4096 Sep  5 11:35 Downloads
drwx------. 15 daniel daniel unconfined_u:object_r:unlabeled_t:s0  4096 Sep 13 13:37 Dropbox
drwxr-xr-x.  2 daniel daniel unconfined_u:object_r:unlabeled_t:s0  4096 May 25 18:59 Music
drwxr-xr-x.  2 daniel daniel system_u:object_r:fusefs_t:s0            0 Jan  1  1970 notes
drwxrwxr-x.  4 daniel daniel unconfined_u:object_r:unlabeled_t:s0  4096 Sep 13 14:39 org
-rw-rw-r--.  1 daniel daniel unconfined_u:object_r:unlabeled_t:s0 17311 Sep 13 13:10 out.out
drwxr-xr-x.  3 daniel daniel unconfined_u:object_r:unlabeled_t:s0  4096 Sep  1 17:58 Pictures
drwxr-xr-x.  2 daniel daniel unconfined_u:object_r:unlabeled_t:s0  4096 May 25 18:59 Public
drwxr-xr-x.  2 daniel daniel unconfined_u:object_r:unlabeled_t:s0  4096 May 25 18:59 Templates
drwxrwxr-x.  2 daniel daniel unconfined_u:object_r:unlabeled_t:s0  4096 Aug 29 21:03 tmp
drwxr-xr-x.  2 daniel daniel unconfined_u:object_r:unlabeled_t:s0  4096 Aug 29 18:40 Videos
```

I'm running Fedora Linux 32

Anyone help would be appreciated!

Comment: Ctrl + Alt + F2 -> login -> what does `pwd` return?

Comment: What is the output of `ls -lZ $HOME`?

Comment: @jsbillings I've updated my post with the output of `ls -lZ`

Comment: It could be setlinux (the quick check to see if this is so is `sudo setenforce 0`, which would cancel that until a reboot or reset with `setenforce`).  If that's the case (not mentioned in the question), it could be failing due to being NFS-mounted (or permissions, etc).  For permissions, `restorecon` is the place to start reading.

Comment: Right, I figured as much.  This should fix the labels: `restorecon -rv /home`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like when you created your new /home directory, it wasn’t labeled as a home directory, so when you log in, selinux prohibits your session from accessing it. Once you are logged in, you can cd into it, but it’s mislabeled.

Run a `restorecon` as root to fix this:

```
# restorecon -r -v /home
```